# Array and objects as a database

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, object

I'm making a login system!
for storing data I put an array with objects to be like a database.
When I check that username and password exist in the database everything works fine,but if i do another check for example if the username and password fields are filled then it doesn't work properly.
when I add this check to any then when I type in an existing username and password then I get the "error username or password" message.

```
<input type="text" id='username'>
<input type="password" id='password'>
<input type="submit" id="submitlogin" value="Login" onclick="login()">
```

```
var database = [
        {
            username: "amr",
            password: "123",
        },
        {
            username: "asmr",
            password: "321",
        },
        {
            username: "amrik",
            password: "1234",
        }
]
function login (){
var user = document.getElementById('username').value;
var pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
for(var i = 0; i < database.length; i++)
{     if(user === "" && pass === "")
      {
         alert("enter username and password");
         return;
      }
      if(user === database[i].username && pass === database[i].password) {
        window.location.href = "index.html";
      } 
}
    alert("error username or password");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use a variable to check the login status?

```
function login (){
var user = document.getElementById('username').value;
var pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
var loggedIn = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < database.length; i++)
{     if(user === "" && pass === "")
      {
         alert("enter username and password");
         return;
      }
      if(user === database[i].username && pass === database[i].password) {
        loggedIn = 1;
        window.location.href = "index.html";
      } 
}

if(loggedIn == 0)
{
    alert("error username or password");
}

    return;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/40wonL6y/

Answer (score 2):

Consider the structure of your code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
    //...
}
alert("error username or password");
```

This alert *always* executes, because there's no condition in which it wouldn't.  It looks like you're expecting this to end execution of the code on the page:

```
window.location.href = "index.html";
```

It doesn't.

The simplest change would likely just be to do what you already do in one of your conditions, return from the function:

```
window.location.href = "index.html";
return;
```

---

Also, as an aside, be aware that any client-side "login system" like this is purely for practicing code and should never actually be used.  It would be trivial for a user to observe the "database" here and see the usernames/passwords.